# How to make a Lua function block until a closure is called

Tags: lua, coroutine

I have a custom Lua interpreter executable with some basic socket functionality built in. It's not Luasocket, and as much as I would like to be using Luasocket here, I can't (so please don't suggest it as an answer).

The socket API that I'm working with relies on asynchronous closures to signal that a network operation is complete. So, in the code below, `socketConnect()` returns immediately and then `onConnect()` is called later on when the connection is complete.

```
local function onConnect(cookie, err, sock)
  print("Connected!")
end

local function connect(host, port)
  local success, err = socketConnect(host, port, onConnect)
  print("Connecting...")
end
```

So, here's the question. I want to make the `connect()` function block until the `onConnect()` closure is called. I'm pretty new at Lua, but I'm hoping that coroutines might be helpful here?

EDIT: Here's my attempt at making the function block by using a coroutine:

```
local connected = false
local function onConnect(cookie, err, sock)
  print("Connected!")
  connected = true
end

local coroConnect = coroutine.create(
  function()
    local success, err = socketConnect(m_sHost, m_nPort, onConnect);
    while not connected do
      coroutine.yield()
    end
  end
)

local function connect(sHost, nPort)
  m_sHost = sHost
  m_nPort = nPort
  while not coroutine.status(coroConnect) ~= "dead" do
    coroutine.resume(coroConnect)
    print("Connecting...")
  end
end
```

Comment: Lua doesn't support multithreading or asynchronous callbacks, so either `socketConnect` calls the callback before it returns or the code uses some multithreading extension, in which case it would be helpful to know which one.

Comment: My *custom* Lua interpreter does have a worker thread from which the callback is called. If I were to call the above connect(), the print output would be "Connecting... Connected!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use coroutines, something along these lines may work for you (or give you an idea on what to try):

```
-- this should really be a socket property, but good enough for this example
local connected
local function onConnect(cookie, err, sock)
  print("Connected!")
  connected = true
end

local function connect(host, port)
  connected = false
  local success, err = socketConnect(host, port, onConnect)
  while not connected do
    coroutine.yield()
  end
  print("Connecting...")
end
```

If you now create a coroutine from `connect` function and continue calling that coroutine with `coroutine.resume` until it's completed (`coroutine.status` for that coroutine will return 'dead'), you will get the desired result. Obviously, you can move that `while` loop into `socketConnect` function itself, which will make is synchronous from the user perspective as it won't return anything until `onConnect` is executed.

Comment: Paul, I tried that approach, but the coroutine continues indefinitely. :/ I was hoping that I was doing it wrong, and that there was some magical sauce to make it work, but I suspect that the architecture of my custom interpreter is at the root of this issue.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, since I think the suggestion is a sound one, even though it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Hm, I would not expect the coroutine to continue indefinitely as after printing "Connecting...", it would finished and returned, which would make it status "dead". It seems like you may not be doing the last "resume" calls, which leaves the coroutine in "unfihised" status. This is still not a big issue as if there are not other references pointing to it, it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Paul, see my edit with my attempt using a coroutine. With this code, I get "Connecting..." over and over again, but it never gets to "Connected!".

Comment: @mikejonesguy, this won't work; before `coroutine.resume(coroConnect)` you need to do some work that `socketConnect` is doing and that calls `onConnect` in the end. If there is another coroutine that does this work ("a worker thread from which the callback is called"), then you need to add `coroutine.resume(workerThread)` (or something along these lines) before `coroutine.resume(coroConnect)`.

Comment: The "worker thread" is in the compiled C code of the custom Lua exe I'm running against -- all of the guts of the socket API is built in to that exe, so I unfortunately don't have the kind of access that you're implying.

Comment: That's fine, but between the calls to `coroutine.resume(coroConnect)` there *has to be some work done by that worker thread*, which gets you closer to calling `onConnect`. At some point that worker thread will call `onConnect`, which will set the flag and the next call to `coroutine.resume(coroConnect)` will check the flag (which will be true) and complete the coroutine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63530/discussion-between-mikejonesguy-and-paul-kulchenko).

Comment: Any resolution here?